# "Вручную" расшифровать ответ от сайта формата "Content-Encoding: br"

Tags: c#

Как это сделать?
Запросы отправлячются через TcpClient. Поэтому тело ответа походу декодировать самому нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Content-Encoding: br

Это [Brotly](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli) - алгоритм сжатия данных.

Для работы с ним есть целая библиотека [Brotly.NET](https://github.com/XieJJ99/brotli.net/), которая также доступна через [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Brotli.NET/).

Так что обрабатывать такой ответ полностью вручную нет необходимости.

К слову, работа с этой библиотекой уже обсуждалась на enSO ([здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075492/compile-brotli-into-a-dll-net-can-reference)).